# Why can't I make comments over notifying users about content issues?

Tags: discussion, support

Doktor Mayhem has posted this comment to me:

> Maika, editing out that word was okay, but making comments like yours about something so minor is really not appropriate. If you have an issue with a particular swear word, then just edit it out, or if you think it is serious, flag for a moderator. Please don't exaggerate issues like this!

(A comment on here: [What are the benefits and drawbacks of the Floyd Rose SpeedLoader tremolo system?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/what-are-the-benefits-and-drawbacks-of-the-floyd-rose-speedloader-tremolo-system/1571?noredirect=1#comment136537_1571))

---

Why can't I make comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not about making comments - it is about making inappropriate comments!

You wrote:

> Luiscencio, we take inappropriate content ***extremely seriously*** on Stack Exchange. Please be aware.

On a post which said:

> I played once with this... I had an awful time trying to tune the goddamn guitar also if you palm mute to hard you will end with a unbalanced bridge... personal exp.

In general, if you see something as minor as that, just edit the word out - as long as it doesn't change the meaning of the sentence. The comment you left to the OP was **extreme** and not very welcoming. As a rule, while Stack Exchange does take inappropriate content seriously, this was not very inappropriate at all - it was an expression of intensity/frustration, so just edit it and leave any feedback for the OP in the edit reason.

A word of caution - if the word was in the title of a song, however, editing it would be rejected, as that would change the meaning of the post!

Comment: see these two posts for thoughts: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3199/104 and https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3198/104

Answer (score 2):

Because it creates needless work for people. If you can make an edit that improves a post, just make the edit. If you make a comment instead, then someone else has to come along, see the comment, make the edit that you could have made in the first place, and then flag your comment as "no longer needed", and then you or a moderator have to come along later and delete the comment.

Even if you're new and unsure if your edit is the right thing to do, making the edit puts it into a review queue. Then it's just one click for somebody to agree or disagree with your suggestion, and it's still quicker than this to-and-fro with comments.

There's nothing *wrong* with commenting, it's just a needless extra step in this case. Commenting is appropriate if you want to improve a post but can't do it yourself: e.g. if the post lacks some information that you don't know, or if it's unclear and you can't clarify it because you don't understand.