# Edits: Foul Language in a song warranting removal of link?

Tags: discussion

In relation to [To summarily edit out offensive language?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2358/45266), I just saw another edit that I feel was a little over-the-top. I think this one should probably be okay given that the song in question simply happened to use profanity, and we cannot pretend that music doesn't use foul language on occasion.

This one:

[image: Proposed Edit]

And in regards to the question I linked, this is a pretty good example of what I feel is too harsh on the edit comments.

Comment: Hi User45266.  I am the one who suggested the edit.  The title of the link contains a bad word, and when we click on the link, it redirects to an inappropriate website.  In fact, I wrote a comment that is shown on the top of the attachment.  It is not nice to put links on posts that redirect users to bad sites or even **contain** offensive language in its own title.  In fact, I personally would have the edit approved.  Plus, doing so on Stack Exchange can end up with the post being removed, and the uploader would end up losing reputation for this.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya In case you didn't realise from my carefully-edited cropping of the screenshot, I intentionally left your username out of the question; I wouldn't want to make anyone feel as though I were singling them out with this kind of post.

Comment: May I suggest a more clearer explanation of why you intentionally left out my name, please?

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya Well, I wouldn't want to seem to be making fun of your post or anything. Why, did you want your username mentioned? (And no, this isn't general SE policy or anything, I just thought it would be a respectful thing to do.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a terrible idea to allow edits that censor the music that posters are allowed to ask about. Note that here I am talking about the music referenced in the post, not about the language of the post itself. In my opinion, this edit should be rejected, and I have cast my vote to reject the edit.

Policing content on a publicly available platform presents challenges, and some content may be genuinely inappropriate. Yet, drawing that line is not a simple matter, and those without full editing privileges should not be engaging in this type of content policing.

When a link to a piece of music offends, it would be better to flag for moderator attention if you must, as they are probably the only ones who should be making these decisions.